# Laravel mail: how to add user's form answers to mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

Basically , I have a form  and I want to send confirmation link after form posted , also I want to add all form fields and answers of users .I stored all  data in my controller's store function and  in the same function I wrote this mail function . However, I  could not manage to add user's answers .

```
    Mail::send('isim',['name'=>'email'],function($message){
        $message->to('mail','mail')-      >from('email','name')->subject('welcome');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your user model has attributes `name` and a `relationship` to fetch answers called `answers`, You can do the following.

Here, `Mail::send('isim',['name'=>$user->name,'answers'=>$user->answers]` will inject `$name` and `$answers` to your view. You can access them there.

`use ($user)` will inject the `$user` variable to the function inside where you set the receiver's email address.

```
$user= //fetch user from the database as you wish
Mail::send('isim',['name'=>$user->name,'answers'=>$user->answers],function($message) use ($user){
    $message->to('mail',$user->email)->from('email',"Your email address")->subject('welcome');
});
```